# Multiple date formats, towards one proper format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date columns with multiple dates:

```
Date
2022-01-01 00:00:00
jan 20
january 19
```

How can I convert them, in a scalable way (without dictionary), to a proper date time format?

I tried:

```
df['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce').astype(str)

df['Date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce', ,yearfirst = False, format = '%B %y')).astype(str)

df['Date1'] = df['Date1'].str.replace('NaT','')
df['Date2'] = df['Date2'].str.replace('NaT','')
```

Then, I merged the two columns, with:

```
df['Date3'] = df['Date1'] + df['Date2']
```

But, this is not working, since I need to create another format (for the not-abbreviation months).
But when adding the logic above, but then changing the %B for %b, it is duplicating some months (like may, which is both: an abbreviation and full month).

I would like to have the end result:

```
2022-01-01
2020-01-01
2019-01-01
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about the date1, date2, etc. columns and what they contain exactly?

Comment: is this the only 3 types of format you'll have to handle?

Comment: Yes, they are created in the example above. Date 1 is basically a try to get the dates (with 2020-01-01 00:00:00 format) from the date column, while Date2 is trying to get the same date format, but then for dates with a 'jan 20' format. Date3 is when I try to combine the columns

Comment: @mozway for now yes, but I can imagine - when extracting more data- that there are more messed up formats. So hope to find a scalable -non dictionary- solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combine_first` to try it with a variety of different date formats:

```py
date = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors="coerce")

for format in ["%b %y", "%B %y"]:
    date = date.combine_first(pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format=format, errors="coerce"))

df["Date"] = date
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to handle all formats at once.

What you can do is use successive methods. Here I combined the "january 19" and "jan 20" using a regex. You can use additional `.fillna(<new_converter>)` should you find more formats in the future.

```
(pd
 .to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')
 .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace('([a-z]{3})[a-z]+', r'\1', regex=True),
                        errors='coerce', yearfirst=False, format='%b %y')
        )
)
```

output:

```
0   2022-01-01
1   2020-01-01
2   2019-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```